# Adding subobject to object

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to add a subobject to object like

```
var myObj = myObj || {};
myObj.prototype.subObj = {
  'funk': function() {
    console.log('Funky success');
  }
};
```

but I keep getting the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'subObj' of undefined

Comment: because prototype is undefined

Comment: the *prototype* is an attribute of *function* not *Object*. You can just attach your subobject to *myObj.subObj*.

Comment: Instance of object hasn't prototype. The type(its constructor) has it.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini Badly mixing patterns I am. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use prototypes, you must create your objects with functions:

```
function myObj() { }

myObj.prototype.subObj = {
  'funk': function() {
    console.log('Funky success');
  }
};

var obj = new myObj();
obj.subObj.funk(); // => 'Funky success'
```

But you can always do:

```
var myObj = {}

myObj.subObj = {
      'funk': function() {
        console.log('Funky success');
      }
    };

myObj.subObj.funk(); // => 'Funky success'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let myObj = {
    subObj: {
        funk: function () {
            // whatever
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an oversimplified example of me trying to set up namespacing, that is, I'm going to be declaring these subobjects in separate files to keep everything clean so what you've done here won't work for me. But the guys in the comments got me out of trouble. Thanks, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign to `myObj.prototype.subObj` unless `myObj.prototype` already exists and contains an object. Javascript doesn't automatically create intermediate objects in the hierarchy. So you could do:

```
var myObj = myObj || { prototype: {} };
myObj.prototype.subObj = {
  'funk': function() {
    console.log('Funky success');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In a very similar fashion to your approach in ES6 you can safely do like this;

```js
var myObj = myObj || {};
myObj.__proto__.subObj = {
  'funk': function() {
    console.log('Funky success');
  }
};

myObj.subObj.funk();
```

But you can also use `Object.create()` method as follows;

```js
var prototype = {
                 subObj : {
                           funk: function() {
                                   console.log('Funky success');
                                 }
                          }
                },
        myObj = myObj || Object.create(prototype);
myObj.subObj.funk();
```